# Increase spacing of every third row in Grid

Tags: grid-layouts

I have a grid whose number of rows is a multiple of 3, for example

```
Grid[{{a, a},{a, a},{a, a},{a, a},{a, a},{a, a}}]
```

Is there an automatic way using the option spacings, so that at every third row the spacing is increased? I tried

```
Grid[{{a, a},{a, a},{a, a},{a, a},{a, a},{a, a}},Spacings -> {0, {0, 0, 3}}]
```

but this only inserts a spacing of 3 in the third row without repeating the pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an additional list wrapper:

```
Grid[{{a, a}, {a, a}, {a, a}, {a, a}, {a, a}, {a, a}}, 
 Spacings -> {0, {{0, 0, 3}}}]
```

[image]

Comment: That does the trick, thank you!